# How to increase resolution maintaining Hertz

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution

I have a [Samsung SyncMaster 932MW LCD TV](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_UK&CttFileID=1573511&CDCttType=UM&ModelType=N&ModelName=932MW&VPath=UM/200707/20070731181525453_BN59-00625A-01Eng.pdf&OriginYN=N), that I connected as a secondary monitor via HDMI to my laptop [AsusVivoBook S15 X510UF](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X510UF/specifications/) with **Windows 10 build 1903**. It has an integrated Intel video card and a Nvidia GeForce MX130. The CPU is an Intel Core i5.

The only frequency the TV supports is **59Hz** and the only resolution with that frequency is **640 x 480**. The thing I don't like (before the resolution) is that with low resolution, Windows makes things bigger, and so It's very difficult to work with (the app and other elements dimension is set to 100% in Windows settings, so it isn't possible to lower it).

Also, in the higher resolutions, there isn't even one with **59Hz**.

***How can I increase the resolution while maintaining the refresh rate?***

Comment: @K7AAY It isn't duplicate, the other post is made by me and I asked for a solution to the tv that didn't even recognize the signal. Now I'm trying to increase the resolution. **However** I have a _VivoBook S15 X510UF_ with an integrated Intel video card and a Nvidia GeForce MX130. The CPU is an Intel Core i5. **to answer the first comment**, I just tried to add a custom resolution from the Intel graphics control panel (because the Nvidia one has only 3D settings) with the resolution in the manual. However it doesn't change. In the Windows Settings is always 640x480 59Hz.

Comment: Page 59 of your manual (web link in the question above) shows the monitor will do 1440 x 900 @ 60HZ (well, 59.887Hz), and up to 75 Hz at 1280 x 1024 and below, so it's not your monitor. Is the video feeding the external monitor set to mirror the laptop's screen, or is it set to use its own resolution and frequency? Please advise.

Comment: Please take a look at the NVIDIA Control Panel again after looking at this alternate example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFZ5B.png _Adjust desktop size and position_ and _Set up multiple displays_ let me do what you want to do with my NVIDIA card.

Comment: @K7AAY The TV (not monitor) acts like a secondary **extended** monitor, so it has its own resolution. Setting the resolution [as you say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PQUP.jpg), it is the same and in Windows settings [it's still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC5jB.png). About the Nvidia control panel, it's showing [3D options only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahSww.png).

Comment: @K7AAY I downloaded the DHC driver but it says I have to download the standard one. I downloaded it and installed, but there are still only 3D settings

Comment: Time for greater minds than mine to step in.

Comment: Your video card is capable of 3840x2160 but is working at the lowest possible resolution. Checks: (1) Run `msconfig`, Boot tab, where all options need to be unchecked. (2) Install the latest [NVIDIA 442.19 driver](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/nvidia-geforce-mx130) from February 2020. (3) Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (4) Try another good-quality video cable.

Comment: @harrymc I tried to go to boot tab in msconfig but there's [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4i5J.png), by the way I went to **task manager** on the boot section and deselected everything. (2) I have already installed those **game-ready** drivers from **GeForce Experience**. (3) Runned it and nothing is wrong. (4) I think it's better to resolve without first and in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1528623/how-to-sync-screen-resolution-and-signal-resolution/1528675#1528675) they answered me that my monitor supports only **high-quality VGA**, not **HDMI**. Could it be an option?

Comment: Doesn't sound right : Your monitor can do DVI up to 3840x2160. And even VGA can nowadays do much more than 640x480. My money is on the cable - are you using HDMI or VGA?

Comment: @harrymc I'm using HDMI since it's the only cable I've got now

Comment: Have you tried another cable?

Comment: It looks like the TV is reporting only the "IBM, 640 x 480" preset from page 50 in the manual. That could be due to a setting on the monitor's OSD itself; Or maybe it has been put into some kind of demo/retail mode with a special code on the remote.

Comment: @harrymc please read my two comments on the answer

Comment: I don't see where you have tried another cable. If the problem is the same with another good-quality cable of another make, and if the TV is new, I would ask for an exchange or refund. This TV looks to be defective.

Answer (score 1):

As all suggestions have failed, I return to the only method not yet tried:
Use another good-quality cable (of another make).

If this doesn't work either, and if the TV is new, I would ask for an exchange
or (even better) ask for a refund. This TV looks to be defective.

If this is not possible, and if the TV is still under guarantee, then use it
to ask for support.

Comment: In fact I'm gonna go to my local shop to buy a HDMI -> DVI since, yesterday, the cable I have supported even 1280x720 with this TV (but then the resolution disappeared as I rebooted the PC, but that's another story) so I don't think it's a problem of the cable HDMI, that's why I'm not gonna buy another HDMI. The TV is very old (about 2008), I don't think it's still under guarantee.

Comment: I ordered it on Amazon since I didn't find it in my local store. So, since I'm sure this is the right answer and remains only 1 day to the end of the bounty, I give you 50 rep and will accept the answer when I'll receive and try the cable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with an annoying TV in the past. Here are some troubleshooting steps (mostly in powershell) that helped me find more definitive answers on what is happening:

1. Disconnect all other displays, including the laptop display (set it to "Disconnect" in the Display Settings), and see if the available resolutions change
2. Try out the following commands to troubleshoot what Windows can see while your external monitor is the primary:

**powershell:**

```
# Check that the display is showing up, and that it's using the nvidia adapter:
Get-WMIObject win32_videocontroller | select caption,videomodedescription,*refresh*

# Example output:
caption              : Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
videomodedescription : 3000 x 2000 x 4294967296 colors
CurrentRefreshRate   : 59
MaxRefreshRate       : 59
MinRefreshRate       : 59


# check the full list of what Windows thinks it can run with, these don't always match with the list in the GUI:
Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_VideoControllerResolution | select caption

# Example:
320 x 240 x 4294967296 colors @ 59 Hertz  
640 x 480 x 4294967296 colors @ 59 Hertz  
800 x 600 x 4294967296 colors @ 59 Hertz  
1024 x 768 x 4294967296 colors @ 59 Hertz


# check the screen information for all your monitors:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens

# Example output:
BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY2
Primary      : True
WorkingArea  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1050}
```

If any of these give results you don't expect, you may want to investigate the following:

1. Power cycle it all! Newer monitors are often never actually powered down (the power button on mine just puts it to sleep) and weird things can happen...
2. Graphics drivers, and other drivers in general should be as up to date as possible
3. Other software that manages resolutions/desktop settings: USB "Dock" Drivers, displaylink, Dual Monitor Tools, DisplayFusion, etc. all can interfere with a temperamental driver.
4. Some cables, either through damage or... cheapness, can cause resolution handshakes to fail (640x480 is a default fallback resolution). Try out getting a $3 replacement or an even cheaper VGA/DVI cable if your laptop supports it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 1) When I select "only second screen", the screen itself gives an error "mode not supported", so I can't see if it works with other resolutions. 2) I posted all the results [here](https://pastebin.com/zDD5CrzZ). I didn't encounter problems with the output but I did the last four things anyway: 1) It's old, did it a lot of times and didn't change anything. 2) All up to date! 3) Nothing of that installed. 4) I will go tomorrow to my local shop to get a HDMI -> DVI cable since, from what I understood, the TV supports HDMI only as TV mode and monitor with DVI and VGA.

Comment: I tried all the resolution in the Windows settings' advanced screen settings and found that now the higher one supported is 1280x720@59 and so I came out with a conclusion: it works only with a frequency minor than 60. **BUT** in the standard resolutions there are only a few with 59Hz, including 640x480 **AND** if I touch any settings in the Intel Control Panel, i.e. for inserting custom resolution or even those related to overscanning, the Windows settings resolution goes up to 1440x900@60 (I don't know why at all) and the monitor doesn't support it. How do I avoid this?

Comment: It looks like your HDMI out is actually running off of the intel uhd 620 based off the command output, so that's one part of the mystery (maybe check with the nvidia control panel like here? https://imgur.com/b6VFBJb). I've had strange issues with the intel display manager as well - maybe set back to defaults? Forcing a specific resolution that way is not something most monitors will allow. Can you set the adapter to 60 or 75hz on any resolution? The tv shouldn't choke out, just maybe flicker.

Comment: Like I said in a previous comment, I have an Optimus system, so I only have [3D settings in Nvidia Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ2FE.png). What do you mean by adapter? By the way it supports only 59Hz like I said in the last comment, otherwise it won't work in any way.

Comment: Ah, I'm not as familiar with optimus, but the win32_videocontroller that's in use is the 620, so the issue is less likely in the nvidia side of things. Do you have better resolutions in the display adapter properties > Adapter > List All Modes, or do they match what you had? https://imgur.com/qpzW1UY

Comment: Actually I have [a lot of other resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bOJp.png) but, as I said before, I've tried them all and the only few that are supported are the ones with 59Hz or less (there are three or four and these resolutions stop at 1280x720, after there aren't with 59Hz), not 60.