# How to sync screen resolution and signal resolution

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, asus-laptop, intel-graphics

I have a **Asus VivoBook S15** laptop, which has an Optimus system (**Nvidia MX130** + **Intel UHD Graphics 620**). I also use a secondary monitor, a very old (around 2008) **Samsung SyncMaster 932MW**, it supports only [the lowest resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34d8I.png) because trying to change the resolution to anything but that one, [the screen resolution is right but the signal resolution goes up to the highest resolution **1440x900**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbxUZ.png). When a resolution different from the first is set, the monitor gives an error message ["mode not supported"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Mxt.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Samsung SyncMaster 932MW is notable for being as much a TV as a monitor. And, from [the manual](https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/1796641/?page=19), it appears the "monitor" portion is only available via the DVI and VGA port (not the HDMI). The HDMI port is likely connected to a much simpler signal processor that can't handle more than a few specific resolutions and refresh rates (ie 720p, 1080p, 1080i, etc).

You might be able to make it work with an HDMI-to-DVI adapter but there's no guarantee.